# How to place an icon into the title of a custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, icons, title

I'd like to place a drawable into a dialogs title bar. I tried the following:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.some_icon);
dialog.setTitle(R.string.my_dialog_title);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
...
```

The icon doesn't show up but the title moves a little to the right. It seems the dialog reserves space for the drawable but doesn't draw it. I tried several different icons (also from the android resources) but non of them worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Call `setFeatureDrawableResource()` *after* `show()`.

No idea why this works. :)

Comment: Use this and you put it before the show.
requestWindowFeature --> setContentView --> setFeatureDrawableResource

Comment: This may also be used in an activity

Comment: It seems to be sufficient to just place it after setContentView(...)

Comment: Any way to set on onClick listener on this drawable?

Answer (score 15):

Here is solution

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setTitle(R.string.my_dialog_title);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.some_icon);
dialog.show();
```

If you want your dialog look like a activity than add theme to dialog as follow

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also extend the `Dialog` class like so:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTitle("Some Title");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.my_icon);
        super.onStart();
    }
```

i.e. you prepare your window feature in constructor and then set concrete resource in onStart.

So, in you main code you can simply use:

```
    CustomDialog cd = new CustomDialog(getActivity());
    rd.show();
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that works when you're overriding `onCreateView(...)` instead of `onCreateDialog(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
setIcon(R.drawable.image_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is THE solution.  Follow the recipe and you shall have your icon!  Note: order is very important...

```
        final Dialog yourDialog = new Dialog(YourClass.this);
            yourDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);  //must come BEFORE setContentView
            yourDialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourDialog_layout);
            yourDialog.setTitle("Your Title");
            yourDialog.setCancelable(true);  
            yourDialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.your_icon);  //must come AFTER setContentView
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work in a different way, thanks to the Smaïl Hammour post.

Place this static method in your preferred tool class:

```
public static void msgBox( String msg, String title, int type, final Context c){

    int theIcon = drawable.ic_dialog_alert;

    switch(type){
    case YourToolClass.CONFIRMATION:
        theIcon = drawable.ic_menu_help;
        break;      
    case YourToolClass.INFO:
        theIcon = drawable.ic_dialog_info;
        break;
    case YourToolClass.ALERT:
    default:
    }

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

    /* Here enters the .setIcon: */
builder.setMessage(msg) .setTitle (title) .setIcon(theIcon);

builder.setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        /*  */
    }
}); 


AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); 
dialog.show();

}
```

To invoke:

```
YourToolClass.msgBox("the main message goes here", "Test", getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

calling setFeatureDrawableResource llike this

```
 dialog.show();
 dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.logo_1x);
```

i.e after calling dialog.show() worked perfectly in my case .. thanks .. :)